# Retrieving Hostname value from IIS bindings

Tags: powershell, iis-7

I need to retrieve only the Hostname value from IIS binding and store it in a variable. Is there any way to do this?
Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An IIS binding consists of an IP address, a port and a host name, in the following form:

```
<address>:<port>:<host>
```

So, using the WebAdministration module we can split the binding string and grab the last part, like so:

```
$Binding = Get-WebSite "mySite" | Get-WebBinding |Select -ExpandProperty bindingInformation
$HostName = ($Binding -split ":")[-1]
```

Or, if you're using the [PowerShell snap-in for IIS 7.0](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/powershell/getting-started-with-the-iis-powershell-snap-in):

```
$Binding = (Get-ItemProperty -Path IIS:\Sites\mySite -Name Bindings).Collection.bindingInformation
$HostName = ($Binding -split ":")[-1]
```

Comment: Thank you.
If I have multiple websites how I will generate the same?